# Error with JavaFX Project: ImageIO and BufferedImage not visible

Tags: java, openjfx

I'm working on revamping a JavaFX project I created back in 2018. I have the original main script but now there seems to be 2 FX related errors now. `import javax.imageio.ImageIO; import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;` I am using Apache NetBeans with Maven version 12.5 and I am using OpenJDK 17 and OpenJFX 17.

The error is saying for both that these packages are not visible, and that they are declared in module java.desktop but module com.mycompany.realestate2021 does not read it.

pom.xml portion below

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>RealEstate2021</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.realestate2021.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


How do I fix this issue(s)?
```

Comment: Is your original JavaFX project [modular](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html)? Maybe you can post your `pom.xml` file? Can you also post the entire error message you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `module-info.java` for your project, and make sure that it contains a  line for "java.desktop":

```
module xyz {
    requires transitive java.desktop;
... }
```

This declares that your project uses the definitions from java.desktop - which include BufferedImage. You may also need declarations for JavaFX such as:

```
requires transitive javafx.base;
requires transitive javafx.controls; // etc
requires transitive javafx.graphics;
```

Comment: Thanks I found this file under the <default-package> source.